# With Mermaid flowchart, I want to change the size of Note

Tags: flowchart, mermaid

I use Vim with the mermaid flowchart plugin. The code I'm trying to fix is below.

```
sequenceDiagram
    A ->> B: Hello!
    Note right of A: AAAAAAAAAAAA</br>BBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCC
```

The resulting flowchart is here:

[image: Mermaid Flowchart]

If I use `</br>` to align the sentence, the string `CCCCC` protrudes from the yellow node box. So, I want to enlarge the yellow node box. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the font you're using. I had the same issue and based on this: https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli/issues/419 I added:

```
%%{init: {"fontFamily": "Arial, sans-serif" }}%%
```

to my file and mmdc now scales the notes correctly. Season font choice to taste.